# Module not found when I do a modprobe

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I am trying to install this module: https://github.com/mkottman/acpi_call

I did a make, make install.

I then saw `acpi_call.ko` is in `/lib/modules/4.3.3-5-default/extra/`.

When I do a

> modprobe acpi_call

I get

> modprobe: FATAL: Module acpi_call not found in directory
>   /lib/modules/4.3.3-5-default

Tried putting `acpi_call.ko` in `/lib/modules/4.3.3-5-default` but got the same result.

I would like to make it persistent so that when I reboot, module is loaded. I think it's possible only with modprobe.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If the module .ko file is really under `/lib/modules/4.3.3-5-default/extra/` and `4.3.3-5-default` is indeed your current kernel version, then the problem may simply be that you need to run [`depmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/depmod) to re-create the module dependency list. Run:

```
sudo depmod
```

and try again to `modprobe` the module.

Comment: Running `depmod` without any flags worked for me. `-a` is the default anyway and `-e` doesn't do anything without either `-E` or `-F`.

Comment: How to I probe it if the kernel is not running right now?

Comment: @AliAsgari You can list the loaded modules using the `lsmod` command.

Comment: This really saved me. Please upvote.

Comment: # depmod
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.35_ecoo_81080868: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory

Comment: Note to people who read this: This says `depmod`, not `depend`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is unique, but in my system I rebuilt the kernel and took out a module. I installed the vendors module and could not get the system to boot using the vendors module. In my case I forgot to move all the /lib/modules info, so `modules.builtin` still had the module, that I was upgrading. Manually removing the module from `modules.builtin` and doing the `depmod -a` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Anas Dadi

This will solve it for ubuntu 22.04
after install nvidia gforce i lost sound and Bluetooth devices
With solution of Anas Dadi works fine!

```
sudo apt install linux-generic -y 
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r) -y;
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-$(uname -r) -y;
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) -y;
```

Comment: Thanks for your first answer! You can improve it with two small changes:

* Please fix the punctuation, capitalization, and grammar.
* Remove the first line, and replace "With solution of...." with a link to the solution it references.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35848700)

Answer (score -1):

This will solve it for ubuntu/debian

```
sudo apt install linux-generic -y 
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r) -y;
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-$(uname -r) -y;
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) -y;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try running `make && sudo make install` in the source directory. That should install the module in the right place using the Makefile that comes with your kernel headers.